# Run UPDATE (oracle) , Completing the sequence from dataframe columns

Tags: python

I have the following dataframe (df)

```
id  b  c
1   a  x1
2   a  xx1
3   b  x1
4   d  xxxx1
```

I want to do from my python script is an UPDATE (Oracle database) and that my update is completed and executed from `df`

something like.....

`dupdate = pd.read_sql("update table set column=df['c'] where id = df['id'] and b=df['b']", engine)`

Thanks a lot!